# How can I copy and paste an entire array of data to another section of my workbook when a condition is met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating an excel sheet to visualize a production of a farm. The rows 8 to 20 are leading and contain all the formulas for the data we need. However, as different age batches enter the farm I need the same data as in 1 to 21 to show up below at a later date.

As my first batch of animals start a week 1. My second batch of animals enter my farm at `C27` (week 3). Now I would like to copy ALL the data from row 8 to 20 to row 28 to 40 BUT the starting value of `A8` should end up in `C28` now.

However, my second batch can also enter my farm at `E27` or `G27`. So this copying of the data from row 8 to 20 should be interactive, The data in row 8 to 20 does not move.

So `=IF(C27="START")` THEN the whole array of data in row 8 to 21 should be copied to row 28 to 40 starting at `C28`.
But IF "START" moves to `E27` my copied data should also move.

Does someone has a solution to this problem?

I have managed to make this interactive excel sheet with the formulas in all rows. In total 12 batches, but it makes the document SOOO slow. Therefore I want to copy all the values to other cells so I can remove all those calculations from the sheet.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Hopefully helping foto 1]

[image: Hopefully helping foto 2]

I have made a name tag for the whole array. Called "productionplan1"
Then made a formula:

```
=IF(B27="START";B28="Productionplan1";"")
```

but this copies the whole array of data in the cell of the formula and is not scalable. So I am completely stuck...

Comment: You will need VBA for this.  Formula do not "copy" values.  It will create a live link to the data.  VBA can be programmed to copy the data as desired.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to set-up this VBA?